# How can we cast a string, 21 Jul 2016 23:38:01, into date and time format?

Tags: google-bigquery

How can we cast a column named DateEventRecorded with strings like this 21 Jul 2016 23:38:01 into DATETIME format? The table name is patients_observations.

I tried to cast it using the cast function, but there is an "invalid date" error.

Comment: I suspect you want the [PARSE_DATETIME function](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/datetime_functions#parse_datetime) - have you tried that yet?

Answer (score 0):

Consider below example

```
select parse_datetime('%d %B %Y %T', '21 Jul 2016 23:38:01')
```

with output

[image]

Comment: Have you tried? Did it work for you?